# Roll n dice expectation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value, binomial-distribution

Let's say we have n dice. We roll all of them at the same time. $Z$ denotes the sum of the number of dice that had the same result. For example, if we have rolled 5 dice at the same time, 2 of them yield 1 and 2 of them yield 6, and the last one yields 4, then $Z$ will equal $2+2 =4$.  What is the expectation of $Z$?

I write the probability that each die will show a specific number. with a probability of $1/6$, each die shows the number $i$ (from 1 to 6) and with a probability of $5/6$ it does not show the rest of the numbers, this has a binomial distribution but I'm not sure how to use it to calculate $E(Z)$.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Are you saying that $Z$ is the number of tosses that match some other toss?  So if the string is $1,1,1,1,1$ we get $Z=5$?  If so, linearity should solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, hard to follow : if three dice show a "six" do we take $3+...$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie if three dice yield 6 and two yield 1 then z will be 3+2 =5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understood that $Z$ denotes the number of dice that show a number that also appears on another die. The chance that the number on die $k$ will not repeat on any of  the other dice is $(5/6)^{n-1}$, so
$$E(Z)=n-n(5/6)^{n-1}\,.$$

Comment: How do you calculate (5/6)^n-1 ?

Comment: Suppose the number $a$ appeared on die $k$. For each of the other $n-1$ dice, the chance that they did not yield $a$ is (5/6) and all these events are independent. Finally $6 \cdot(1/6)\cdot (5/6)^{n-1}=(5/6)^{n-1}$.

Comment: I think about it again and how can we be sure that there is not any same number in (5/6)^n-1?

Comment: I don't understand what issue you have. Once you fix that $a$ appears in die $k$, you consider the  $n-1$ other dice. For each one, the chance it does not yield $a$ is $5/6$, and these $n-1$ events are independent. Their intersection has chance $(5/6)^{n-1}$.

Comment: We know that with a probability of 5/6, the number a does not appear on the dice of other people, but at the same time if the number b appears on the dice of 2 or more people who have the probability of 5/6. This again affects the Z number.

Comment: We are using additivity of expectation. Let $I_k$ be the indicator that the number on die $k$ did not appear elsewhere. These variables are dependent but that is OK. We calculate the mean of $I_k$ and add them up. Is that clear?

Comment: yes. thank you!